# Update a partir de alteração no select

Tags: jquery, html5, ajax, jquery-mobile, jquery-validate

Tenho uma lista com vários selects e preciso que ao alterar o option do select seja atualizado no banco de dados. Consigo fazer isso através de ajax + php. Minha duvida na verdade é como disparar o evento a partir da mudança de option. Alguém poderia me dar uma luz? São vários selects e eles devem disparar o evento apenas do select selecionado.

```css
.linha {
  display: block;
  width: 900px;
}
.selects {
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="linha">
  <div class="selects">
    <label>JAN</label>
    <select>
      <option value="N">Não</option>
      <option value="OK">OK</option>
      <option value="">-</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="selects">
    <label>FEV</label>
    <select>
      <option value="N">Não</option>
      <option value="OK">OK</option>
      <option value="">-</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="selects">
    <label>MAR</label>
    <select>
      <option value="N">Não</option>
      <option value="OK">OK</option>
      <option value="">-</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="selects">
    <label>ABR</label>
    <select>
      <option value="N">Não</option>
      <option value="OK">OK</option>
      <option value="">-</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="selects">
    <label>MAI</label>
    <select>
      <option value="N">Não</option>
      <option value="OK">OK</option>
      <option value="">-</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="selects">
    <label>JUN</label>
    <select>
      <option value="N">Não</option>
      <option value="OK">OK</option>
      <option value="">-</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<BR>
<BR>
<div class="linha">
  <div class="selects">
    <label>JAN</label>
    <select>
      <option value="N">Não</option>
      <option value="OK">OK</option>
      <option value="">-</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="selects">
    <label>FEV</label>
    <select>
      <option value="N">Não</option>
      <option value="OK">OK</option>
      <option value="">-</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="selects">
    <label>MAR</label>
    <select>
      <option value="N">Não</option>
      <option value="OK">OK</option>
      <option value="">-</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="selects">
    <label>ABR</label>
    <select>
      <option value="N">Não</option>
      <option value="OK">OK</option>
      <option value="">-</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="selects">
    <label>MAI</label>
    <select>
      <option value="N">Não</option>
      <option value="OK">OK</option>
      <option value="">-</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="selects">
    <label>JUN</label>
    <select>
      <option value="N">Não</option>
      <option value="OK">OK</option>
      <option value="">-</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue um exemplo para simplificar oque você quer fazer, com isso você vai centralizar o update em apenas uma requisição `ajax`, usei o atributo `data`, passando o `data-tipo` para cada select.
Como os valores são parecidos, na requisição `ajax` você vai passar o campo tipo e o campo valor, da uma olhada:

```js
$(function(){
 $('select').change(function(){
     alert('Tipo:'+$(this).attr('data-tipo')+' Valor:'+$(this).val());
  //Faz uma requisição ajax passando tipo e valor
    });
});
```

```css
.linha {
  display: block;
  width: 900px;
}
.selects {
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="linha">
  <div class="selects">
    <label>JAN</label>
    <select data-tipo="JAN">
      <option value="N">Não</option>
      <option value="OK">OK</option>
      <option value="">-</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="selects">
    <label>FEV</label>
    <select data-tipo="FEV">
      <option value="N">Não</option>
      <option value="OK">OK</option>
      <option value="">-</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="selects">
    <label>MAR</label>
    <select data-tipo="MAR">
      <option value="N">Não</option>
      <option value="OK">OK</option>
      <option value="">-</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="selects">
    <label >ABR</label>
    <select data-tipo="ABR">
      <option value="N">Não</option>
      <option value="OK">OK</option>
      <option value="">-</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="selects">
    <label>MAI</label>
    <select data-tipo="MAI">
      <option value="N">Não</option>
      <option value="OK">OK</option>
      <option value="">-</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="selects">
    <label>JUN</label>
    <select data-tipo="JUN">
      <option value="N">Não</option>
      <option value="OK">OK</option>
      <option value="">-</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Pode-se usar de diversas formas, eu sugiro 2:

Primeiro colocar a chamada da função direto no evento do elemento assim:

```
   <select onchange="funcaoJavascript()">
      <option value="N">Não</option>
      <option value="OK">OK</option>
      <option value="">-</option>
    </select>
```

Ou usando jquery pode-se criar um "event listener" que fica observando e esperando o evento ocorrer assim nesse caso é necessário que você especifique cada select com uma class ou um ID se você quiser comportamento diferente para cada select:
Digamos:

```
<select id="teste">

$('#teste').change(function(){
//aqui dentro pode-se referenciar o select que disparou o evento assim $(this)
});
```

Nesse exemplo acima ele vai disparar baseado no id teste, mas você pode fazer um que dispare com qualquer select assim:

```
$('select').change(function(){

});
```

Um exemplo no fiddle pra fechar:

https://jsfiddle.net/65977v9c/

Obs: a função do onchange não consegui fazer funfa no fiddle Oo rs n sei pq tem alguma bruxaria, mas a syntaxe ta lá. abç

Comment: Para finalizar: um exemplo no fiddle com o código dele ;)

Comment: Se faz uma resposta completa filé pros cara marca a outra como certa. =[ desanima

Comment: Desanima não. Não estou dizendo que é o caso, mas nem sempre a resposta marcada é a que vai mais ajudar as pessoas. Normalmente o pessoal presta mais atenção no número de votos do que na resposta marcada como correta.